# Need some sample dcm files for structure report(Ultrasound)

Tags: dicom, sample

I need some sample dcm files for structure report(Ultrasound). Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Report 19 from the link below indicates US structured report, but I'm not sure if it is the exact SOP class you are looking for:

http://www.dclunie.com/medical-image-faq/html/part8.html#DICOMStructuredReportSamples